Deserialize from Json using existing sub objects
Here is my situation: I am trying to use Newtonsoft.Json 13.0.3 to deserialize by using already instanced data.
I know this exists: JsonConvert.PopulateObject but that does not do the trick, bare with me.
// MainData, a class we will let Json.net instanciate
public class MainData
{
  [JsonProperty]
  private List<SmallerData> _smallerDataArray = new();
}

// SmallerData, a class we do not want Json.net to instanciate
public class SmallerData
{
   public int myInt;
}

Imagine the following MainData serialized into a json string called "jsonString"
{
  "$type":"MainData",
  "_smallerDataArray":
  {
    "$type":"List<SmallerData>"
    [
      {
        "$type":"SmallerData",
        "myInt":"0"
      },
      {
        "$type":"SmallerData",
        "myInt":"1"
      },
      {
        "$type":"SmallerData",
        "myInt":"2"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Normally deserialisation code looks like that
public static MainData DeserializeNormaly(string jsonString)
{    
   // here Json.net will create 3 SmallerData instances via RTTI
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainData>(jsonString);
}

But I would like it to look like something like that (that code does not compile)
public class Example
{
   // Creating a pool of 3 SmallerData for the example's sake
   List<SmallerData> _pooledData = new() { new SmallerData(), new SmallerData(), new SmallerData());

  public object MyObjectFactory(Type objectType)
  {
     if(objectType == typeof(SmallerData))
     {
       // Detecting a type we can instaniate from a pool
       SmallerData smallerDataInstance = _pooledData[0];
       _pooledData.RemoveAt(0);
       return smallerDataInstance;
     }
     // Relying of default object creation
     return null;
  }

  public MainData DeserializeFromPool(string jsonString)
  {   
  
   JsonSerializerSettings settings = new();
   settings.ObjectFactory = MyObjectFactory;

   // here Json.net will create 3 SmallerData instances via RTTI
   return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainData>(jsonString, settings);
  }
}

Somehow I would like JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to pull from pooledData when instanciating SmallerData instead of creating new ones.
I have been looking into converters contracts what whatnots but couldn't find a way. Anybody attempted that before ?
In the case you are curious as to why I am trying to do that: this one of the many efforts I am doing to reduce garbage generation during json usage.

I don't get the point. Slap a [JsonIgnore] on the property and populate it with the pool? Other question would then be: why make "SmallerData" collection a property of "MainData" in the first place?

Btw. working with properties rather than public fields should give you a better experience, especially when working with JSON - serialization.

I have doubts that Newtonsoft or any other package can provide such functionality. Bear in mind that you need a mechanism to track the count of free objects in pooledData, add new ones if necessary, and mark the used ones as free when they are.”

It's not quite clear what is the problem. What garbage generation? What is usage (deserialization? serialization?) ? If you are not going to use data, then don't serialize it. As for your specific case, do it other way around: first deserialize json, then override what was deserialized with values you want to and then return.

If you are having performance problems due to excessive memory allocation during JSON deserialization and serialization you might look into System.Text.Json, it is designed to be less memory-intensive than Json.NET e.g. by deserializing directly from UTF-8 byte sequences.  This supposedly makes deserializing from a stream or pipeline (though not from a string) more performant and less memory intensive.

Rather than rewriting your question to add new requirements, you should ask a new question.

That being said, overriding DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract() or DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract) and setting DefaultCreator as shown in this answer to Type resolution in Newtonsoft.Json with custom converter may do what you need.  Does that answer your question?

The question got answered while I was reformulating. Sorry @dbc

Update  If you need to support TypeNameHandling during deserialization you cannot use a CustomCreationConverter<T> as converters are required to handle everything themselves including metadata type resolution.
Instead, create a custom contract resolver, override DefaultContractResolver.CreateObjectContract() and set DefaultCreator to pull objects from your pool as shown in this answer to Type resolution in Newtonsoft.Json with custom converter.
Original answer  You can use a CustomCreationConverter<SmallerData> to pull your objects from their memory pool.
Let's say your SmallerData looks something like this, with a shared pool across all threads:
public class SmallerData
{
    public static ObjectPool<SmallerData> Pool { get; } = new();

    public static SmallerData Create() => Pool.TryRemove(out var o) ? o : new();
}

public class ObjectPool<TObject>
{
    readonly ConcurrentQueue<TObject> queue = new(); // I chose a queue to get FIFO behavior but if you want LIFO use ConcurrentStack<T>
    
    public void Add(TObject obj) => queue.Enqueue(obj ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(obj)));
    public void AddRange(params TObject [] objs) => Array.ForEach(objs, o => Add(o));
    public bool TryRemove( [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.NotNullWhen(returnValue: true)] out TObject? obj) => queue.TryDequeue(out obj) && obj is not null;
}

Then you can define a converter as follows:
public class SmallerDataConverter : CustomCreationConverter<SmallerData>
{
    public override SmallerData Create(Type objectType) => SmallerData.Create();
}

And deserialize by adding the converter to settings:
SmallerData [] itemsToPool = [new(), new(), new()];
SmallerData.Pool.AddRange(itemsToPool);

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{
    Converters = { new SmallerDataConverter() },
};

var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainData>(jsonString, settings);

Or apply the converter directly to SmallerData using attributes to ensure your data class is constructed using the pool whenever it is deserialized:
[JsonConverter(typeof(SmallerDataConverter))]
public class SmallerData
{
    public static ObjectPool<SmallerData> Pool { get; } = new();

    public static SmallerData Create() => Pool.TryRemove(out var o) ? o : new();
}

Either way, pooled instances will be used during deserialization.  Demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CX0OTc
Alternatively, you could eliminate the global pool and make a pool local to each converter, like so:
public class SmallerDataConverter : CustomCreationConverter<SmallerData>
{
    public ConcurrentQueue<SmallerData> Queue { get; } = new(); // I chose a queue to get FIFO behavior but if you want LIFO use ConcurrentStack<T>

    public SmallerDataConverter(params SmallerData [] objs) => Array.ForEach(objs, o => Queue.Enqueue(o ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(o))));

    public override SmallerData Create(Type objectType) => Queue.TryDequeue(out var o) && o is not null ? o : new();
}

However, with this approach you will be unable to apply the converter via attributes and will need to pass the items to be pooled into the converter constructor, like so:
SmallerData [] itemsToPool = [new(), new(), new()];
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{
    Converters = { new SmallerDataConverter(itemsToPool) },
};

var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MainData>(jsonString, settings);

Even if the pool is local to a given converter it is a good idea to make it thread-safe as many applications share settings across threads.
Demo fiddle #2 here.

Thanks ! that is a quality answer and exactly what I was looking for. I think the reformulation was necessary anyway as my question was not very clear.

@OeilDeLance - I though the original version was clear enough.  That being said, given your modified question, CustomCreationConverter<SmallerData> does not work with TypeNameHandling.  If you also need type resolution + custom object construction see Type resolution in Newtonsoft.Json with custom converter.

Interesting. You mean with TypeNameHandling.All that generates the "$type" things. Ok I am having al look now.
I need this indeed.

@OeilDeLance - if you do need it you will need a custom contract resolver like the one from the other question.

Yeah that's gonna be useful indeed. Thanks!
You're really knowledgable about Json.net ! Impressive.
Any other tips about avoiding garbage generation ?

One suggestion: you should deserialize directly from your JSON stream rather than loading a string, then deserializing the string. See Newtonsoft's Performance Tips: Optimize Memory Usage.  You should also cache and reuse your custom contract resolver if you create one.
